# spring mvc special characters

Tags: regex, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to add a field with special characters like "Patrícia" or "José" and since that field is a Name I used a regex pattern from

```
^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00FF]+
```

tested in https://regexr.com/

This is the field inside the user model:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer id;

(etc)

@Column(name = "name")
@Pattern(regexp = " ^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00FF]+" , message = "{user.name.pattern}")
@NotEmpty(message = "{user.name.empty}")
@Size(min=1, max=40, message = " {user.name.size}")
private String name;

(getters/setters/constructor)
```

If I add Patricia or Jose, for example the validation succeeds and the user gets inserted. The regex seems ok in the regExr using those names...

This is the error I get:

```
Hibernate: insert into user (f1, f2, f3, last_name, name, f6, f7, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-05-22 17:40:34.622  WARN 8475 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2018-05-22 17:40:34.623 ERROR 8475 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'
2018-05-22 17:40:34.624  INFO 8475 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2018-05-22 17:40:34.626 ERROR 8475 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2018-05-22 17:40:34.664 ERROR 8475 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

What does the primary key has to do with the name validation?
What can I be doing wrong?

Thank you,

Eunito.

Comment: Isn't this a database issue? You should debug the insert statements generated by Hibernate, and check the unique constraints in the database.

Comment: Fixed it droping all tables and changing from auto-generate to identity.